# Select the maximum of a dimension the from dataset

Tags: matlab

I have an `n`-D data set and I would like to select data for the maximum value of the dimension `n`

`data_finale` has the size: `172299*11*5`, and I would like to find a more efficient way than the loop below to take values for the maximum of `data_finale(ii,:,5)`

```
for ii=1:size(data_finale,1)
     [II JJ]=max(squeeze(data_finale(ii,:,5)));
     data_finale_opt(ii,:)=squeeze(data_finale(ii,JJ,:));
     clear II JJ
end
```

Comment: To improve efficiency, remove the `clear`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get this right, you want to find the maximum based on the dimension of the matrix as in a XxYxZ matrix, you would like to find the maximum along the X dim, Y dim, and Z dim. If this is the case, why not use the [max](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) function with dimension selectivity? You are already using max to find the largest number.

```
s = rng(8675309); % set random # gen
test = rand(13,4,6)*50;   % creates a 3D matrix

[Xm, Xidx] = max(test,[],1) % Finds max across X dim 
[Ym, Yidx] = max(test,[],2) % Finds max across Y dim
[Zm, Zidx] = max(test,[],3) % Finds max across Z dim
```

I have been going through the code you supplied and I'm trying to figure out exactly what your doing. Is the code right as I'm a bit confused as what your trying to pull out.

either way.

Using the max function on the 5th Z plane generated the idx below

```
[~ y]= max(test(:,:,5),[],2)

y =

 1
 3
 1
 4
 4
 4
 2
 3
 2
 3
 3
 3
 3
```

Using your code to squeeze and find max of individual lines generated the following idx:

```
for ii=1:size(test,1)
    [II JJ(ii)]=max(squeeze(test(ii,:,5))); % Tracking your IDX numbers
    data_finale_opt(ii,:)=squeeze(test(ii,JJ(ii),:));
end 

JJ = transpose(JJ)

JJ = 
 1
 3
 1
 4
 4
 4
 2
 3
 2
 3
 3
 3
 3
```

Both your method and my method generated the same IDX values of interest. we can remove the `max` function from the for loop, leaving the pulling of data portion. The code below shows my code, your code, and the speeds.

```
s = rng(8675309); % seed to make same rand values

test = rand(172299,11,5);

%% My code
tic
[~,idx] = max(test(:,:,5),[],2);

data_finale_opt = zeros(size(test,1),size(test,3)); % building container before loop speeds up process as resources don't go into expanding the matrix.
for ii = 1:size(test,1)
    data_finale_opt(ii,:)=squeeze(test(ii,idx(ii),:));
end
toc

%% Your code
tic
for ii=1:size(test,1)
     [II JJ]=max(squeeze(test(ii,:,5)));
     data_finale_opt2(ii,:)=squeeze(test(ii,JJ,:));
     clear II JJ
end

toc

Time elapsed for my code: 0.807906 seconds.
Time elapsed for your code: 4.672404 seconds.
```